# django mezzanine comments with non-ascii cache names

Tags: django, python-3.6, mezzanine

The problem raised from `mezzanine` comment form which stores the author's name in the response cache (as summarized below):

`set_cookie(response, "mezzanine-comment-name", post_data.get("name"))`

Which calls the django `set_cookie` function:

`response.set_cookie(name, value, expires=expires, secure=secure)`

So if the author's name contain non-ascii characters, a well known problem is raised by the server (I've tested it with nginx and also django local server):

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position ...: ordinal not in range(128)`

I've also tried to modify mezzanine source code and put `.encode()` after `post_data.get("name")` but there is an weird line in the first line of the `response.set_cookie` which revokes the encoding!

`value = force_str(value)`

Comment: Have you tried something like `"String æøå".encode('ascii',errors='ignore')`?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Great! It worked! So what to do now? Reporting this issue to mezzanine or something else?

Comment: I don't know. I have not used their software. Did you have to alter their code in order to fix the issue, if yes, then you should open a issue on their github page. If the error was caused by you passing invalid data, then the error might be expected or underlying